# Bootjack - pure polymer-dart implementation

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, rikulo, bootjack

I've been using Bootjack for a while now and it's great. I love how it enables me to create my familiar Bootstrap styled applications with my current favourite programming language, Dart!

However, with all the Material Design and Polymer updates that have emerged lately, shouldn't there be some kind of pure Polymer version of Bootjack, so we can implement Bootstrap elements using Polymer Dart?

I'd like to wire Bootjack's cool Bootstrap elements not programmatically, but by using Polymer elements.

Maybe we can start a Github repository for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have a plan to integrate Polymer with Bootjack. We're happy with what and how easy it can be done in our application ([Quire](https://quire.io)).

You're welcome if you'd like to fork one to integrate them.

Comment: The only problem that I had was with the Modal window.
When I wired a custom polymer element to the Bootjack Modal, it pulled the modal div DOM out of the polymer element and this caused my polymer events to fail. I've created a Bootstrap Modal polymer element based on the JS version here: https://github.com/Turbots/bs-modal-dart

For all other things, I'm still using Bootjack though, its just too easy :-)